# .NET MAUI Process.GetProcesses() iOS & maccatalyst

Tags: system.diagnostics, .net-maui

I am getting warning that GetProcess() and Kill() is not supported on iOS and Mac.

warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 14.2 and later, 'maccatalyst' 14.2 and later. 'Process.GetProcesses()' is unsupported on: 'ios' all versions.
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 14.2 and later, 'maccatalyst' 14.2 and later. 'Process.Kill()' is unsupported on: 'ios' all versions.

Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcesses();

```
        foreach (Process p in processCollection)
        {
            if (p.ProcessName=="skype")   p.Kill();  

        }
```

Comment: What is this code for? If you are trying to close the app then iOS does not support that.

Comment: But if you still wanna do it you can use `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();` on iOS

Comment: @FreakyAli I am creating MAUI app which prevent to open "skype"   while my app is running so I am checking using timer in every 5 sec intervals. If user opened "skype" then kill it. It is working fine in Windows but for mac its giving warning that  Process.GetProcesses() and p.Kill()   not supported.   If I will use Thread.CurrentThread.Abort() for Mac, Will not it kill my app , instead of skype?

Comment: I misunderstood your requirement, I thought you wanted to close your own app. in any case what you are trying to do is not available on mac, Even if you somehow do it AppStore will reject your app